# PHP autoloader duplicate path

Tags: php, duplicates, autoload

i want to learn autoloader in PHP but i loader duplicate my path to my files and its not working.

```
<?php


function myAutoLoader($class){
    $directories = [
        __DIR__ .  "/classes/account/",
        __DIR__ .  "/classes/database/",
    ];
    $extension = ".php";

    foreach ($directories as $directory){
        $fullPath = $directory . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . $extension;
        var_dump($fullPath);
        if(file_exists($fullPath)) {
            require_once $fullPath;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
```

and my Classes, were i want get path:

```
<?php

namespace controllers;


use classes\account\RegisterAccount;

require_once __DIR__ . "/../includes/autoloader.php";

class RegisterController extends RegisterAccount
```

but path its duplicate:
string(94) "C:\xampp\htdocs\reservationSystem\includes/classes/account/classes/account/RegisterAccount.php" string(95)

my directory structure is :

```
project/
├── classes/
│   ├── account/
        |
        ___RegisterAccount.php
│   └── database/
│       └── Connect.php
└── includes/
    └── autoloader.php
```

I searched for answers on youtube and sof but, did not find a solution.

Comment: `use classes\account\RegisterAccount;` means that you're including `classes` and `account` as part of the namespace, so the autoloader will add those path elements after the directory.  Either change your namespace to omit these elements, or change your directory in the autoloader to be just  `__DIR__`

Comment: Ok fine its working but only with use namespace and autoloading, its a good practice?  or i must use only autoloader for this?

Answer (score 1):

The `$class` that's passed into the autoloader is the class including the namespace.

So in your case the value of `$class` is `classes\account\RegisterAccount`

So you can scrap this part

```
$directories = [
    __DIR__ .  "/classes/account/",
    __DIR__ .  "/classes/database/",
];
```

Also, you don't have to return true or false as `spl_autoload_register` returns true if it manages to load the class, and false otherwise.

So you function should look like this

```
function myAutoLoader($class){
    $fullPath = __DIR__ . '/' .  str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    if(file_exists($fullPath)) {
        require_once $fullPath;
    }
}
```